# Simple VLOOKUP using Dictionary in a VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, vlookup

I am looking to do a vlookup via a dictionary in a VBA Macro.  I have seen a few examples around the internet but they are mostly very specific and I am hoping to get assistance with more "bare bones" code.  I will use a simple example of what I would like to achieve:

- Lookup Value to be each cell within a dynamic range starting in cell B2 on the "Orders" Worksheet (bottom row varies)
- Table Array to be on a dynamic range starting in cell E2 and extending to column L on the "Report" Worksheet (Bottom row varies)
- Column Index Number is to be 8 (Column L)
- Range Lookup is to be False

My current code is below:

```
Sub DictionaryVLookup()
Dim x, y, z(1 To 10)
Dim i As Long
Dim dict As Object
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Worksheets("Report").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


x = Sheets("Orders").Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Value
y = Sheets("Report").Range("E2:E" & LastRow).Value    'looks up to this range
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = x(i, 1)
Next i

For i = 1 To UBound(y, 1)
    If dict.exists(y(i, 1)) Then
        z(i) = y(i, 1)
    Else
        z(i) = "NA"
    End If
Next i
Worksheets("Orders").Range("Z2:Z" & LastRow).Value = Application.Transpose(z)    'this is where the values are placed

End Sub
```

I seem to be missing the "lookup" portion, currently this runs without error and simple places the values which are "found" by the lookup, but I don't know how to have the returned value be offset (want to return column L in this example).

Also I did some "Frankenstein" work with this code - so I am not sure why this is present:

```
   Dim x, y, z(1 To 10)
```

the (1 to 10) I will want to be dynamic I would guess.

This is my first attempt at using a dictionary in this fashion -  Hoping to get a basic understanding through this simple example which I can then implement into more involved situations.

I know there are other methods to do what I am describing, but looking to learn specifically about dictionaries.

Thanks in advance for any assistance !

Comment: Do both sheets have the same numbers of rows?  You only have one `LastRow` variable...   It's not clear exactly what you're doing here.

Comment: @TimWilliams For the simple example yes they have the same number of rows on both sheets.  If they did not, I would add a "LastRowTwo for the second sheet.  I am trying to do a basic VLOOKUP using a dictionary.

Comment: I can see you're trying to do a lookup, but your code doesn't make it clear exactly what the intent is.  If you were to use the VLOOKUP() formula, what would that look like?

Comment: @TimWilliams The Standard VLOOKUP Formula would be:
       =VLOOKUP(B2,Report!E1:L10,8,FALSE)

This formula would be in cell Z2 on the "Orders" Worksheet (hopefully that makes sense when combined with the descriptions above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub DictionaryVLookup()

    Dim x, x2, y, y2()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim LastRow As Long, shtOrders As Worksheet, shtReport As Worksheet

    Set shtOrders = Worksheets("Orders")
    Set shtReport = Worksheets("Report")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'get the lookup dictionary from Report
    With shtReport
        LastRow = .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        x = .Range("E2:E" & LastRow).Value
        x2 = .Range("L2:L" & LastRow).Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
            dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = x2(i, 1)
        Next i
    End With

    'map the values
    With shtOrders
        LastRow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        y = .Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Value    'looks up to this range
        ReDim y2(1 To UBound(y, 1), 1 To 1)   '<< size the output array
        For i = 1 To UBound(y, 1)
            If dict.exists(y(i, 1)) Then
                y2(i, 1) = dict(y(i, 1))
            Else
                y2(i, 1) = "NA"
            End If
        Next i
        .Range("Z2:Z" & LastRow).Value = y2  '<< place the output on the sheet
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Generalized @Tim Williams excellent example to have no Hard coded ranges in main sub for helping following users.

```
'In sheet Phones lookup col F  at LogFileSh sheet col CE,CF and return 
'the results in col D sheet Phones. Row of F+D is 2 and row CE+CF is 2.

Sub RunDictionaryVLookup()
Call GeneralDictionaryVLookup(Phones, LogFileSh, "F", "CE", "CF", "D", 2, 2)
End Sub


Sub GeneralDictionaryVLookup(ByVal shtResault As Worksheet, ByVal shtsource As Worksheet, _
ByVal colLOOKUP As String, ByVal colDicLookup As String, ByVal colDicResault As String, ByVal colRESULT As String, _
ByVal rowSource As Long, ByVal rowResult As Long)
    Dim x As Variant, x2 As Variant, y As Variant, y2() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'get the lookup dictionary 
    With shtsource
        LastRow = .Range(colDicLookup & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        x = .Range(colDicLookup & rowSource & ":" & colDicLookup & LastRow).Value
        x2 = .Range(colDicResault & rowSource & ":" & colDicResault & LastRow).Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
            dict.item(x(i, 1)) = x2(i, 1)
            Debug.Print dict.item(x(i, 1))
        Next i
    End With

    'map the values
    With shtResault
        LastRow = .Range(colLOOKUP & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        y = .Range(colLOOKUP & rowResult & ":" & colLOOKUP & LastRow).Value  'looks up to this range
        ReDim y2(1 To UBound(y, 1), 1 To 1)   '<< size the output array
        For i = 1 To UBound(y, 1)
            If dict.Exists(y(i, 1)) Then
                y2(i, 1) = dict(y(i, 1))
            Else
                y2(i, 1) = "NA"
            End If
        Next i
        .Range(colRESULT & rowResult & ":" & colRESULT & LastRow).Value = y2   '<< place the output on the sheet
    End With
End Sub
```